# BufferedWriter is not writing to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, java-io

I want to convert an input stream to byte array. I know I can use IOUtils from commons-io. But I am practicing some basics in java io. I read an xml file using BufferedReader and tried writing it to a ByteArrayOutputStream using BufferedWriter. But its not working.

When I write directly to the ByteArrayOutputStream its working. Whats wrong in my code?

```
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/productInventory.xml");
                ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(arrayOutputStream));
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                bufferedWriter.write(line);
            }
            System.out.println(arrayOutputStream.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I include below line in the loop its working

```
arrayOutputStream.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.getBytes().length);
```

What is wrong while using BufferedWriter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing's wrong - it's just buffering! :D

The BufferedWriter works by filtering everything you send into it into a buffer - when the buffer is full, or when the writer is closed, or flushed, (It's a Closeable, so you should absolutely close it), it sends along those buffered characters to the underlying writer.

If you want to see the underlying writer update you have to either:

1) Fill up the buffer (default size is 8k in Java)

2) Call `.flush()`

3) Call `.close()`

4) As mentioned in comments, you can do a try-with-resources to make the close implicit:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(underlyingWriter)) {
  // doStuff
}
```

Comment: Or do the last one automatically with a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: I called flush(). It worked like a charm. My file size is 6k. You said that the default size is 8k. So what if I have a file of 10k and I dont call flush(). Will it only write the first 8k into the ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: No, it will perform two writes - one write of 8k when the buffer fills, and a second write of 2k when you call `flush()` - (Or, `close()`, which is the better practice)